# How can I upgrade my working Laravel 5.5 to Laravel 6.0

Tags: php, laravel

I installed fresh Laravel 6 in my XAMPP. Now my previous project composer.json file is as

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.5",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
         "cmgmyr/messenger": "^2.14",
        "laravel/cashier": "7.0.*",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "consoletvs/charts": "^4.5",
        "softon/indipay": "^1.0",
        "milon/barcode": "^5.3",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^3.0",
        "razorpay/razorpay": "^2.2",
        "shipu/themevel": "^1.6",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "^1.3",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.37",
        "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^2.0",
        "bavix/laravel-wallet": "^3.2",
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.4",
        "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.1",
        "aminyazdanpanah/php-ffmpeg-video-streaming": "^1.1",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "^1.0",
        "kreait/firebase-php": "^4.35",
        "baklysystems/laravel-chat-messenger": "^1.7",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.1",
        "ktamas77/firebase-php": "^2.2",
        "phpoffice/phppresentation": "^0.9.0",
        "alexusmai/laravel-file-manager": "^2.4",
        "kim/activity": "^1.1",
        "pragmarx/tracker": "^3.5",
        "geoip2/geoip2": "~2.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.4",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.10",
        "dragonmantank/cron-expression": "^2.3",
        "brozot/laravel-fcm": "^1.3"

    },

    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
        "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
         "files":[
           "app/constants.php",
           "app/helpers.php",
           "app/language_helper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "provide": {
        "ext-mongo": "1.6.12"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Reason to upgrade it is I need to connect it with Firebase kreaite/Firebase and that is supporting to 5.8 or above version only.

I tried to do it directly using composer update but fails as lots of other plugin not support this up gradation, Can I directly upgrade to it? Or any other solution if possible without upgrade.

Comment: You can use [this service](https://laravelshift.com) for an automated process, You will need to look at the directory structure when upgrading https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade . Check the official documentation for the upgrading instructions

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your `"laravel/framework": "5.5.*",` to `"laravel/framework": "^6.0",` in your composer.json.

You will receive a few other error due to incompatible version such as from phpunit, you can change them accordingly in your composer.json when you see those errors.